# while loops offset in shell script

Tags: shell, while-loop

I/P file has data as follows:

```
Y
REQUIRES Z
A
REQUIRES B
C
REQUIRES D
REQUIRES E
REQUIRES F
G
REQUIRES H
I
REQUIRES J
```

EXACT OUTPUT FILE REQUIRED:

```
Y REQUIRES Z
A REQUIRES B
C REQUIRES D
C REQUIRES E
C REQUIRES F
G REQUIRES H
I REQUIRES J
```

I am using while loops to traverse the file.

```
while read line
do
if (condition)
{..
}
while read anoterline
do
done
done <inputfile
```

The problem I am facing is that

1. when inner while loop traverses say 4 lines and i break the inner
   loop the outer while loop's offset is set to the offset at which the
   inner while has stopped.
2. So I am missing the 4 lined data in execution of my outer loop. 
   I need the outer while loop to start off from the offset at which it had stopped

---

.

Comment: With respect to the "problem" -- file I/O doesn't work that way (without seeking backwards, and since there's no interface to fseek(), that's not an option here). It's nothing to do with shell's while construct misbehaving when nested, and everything to do with choosing the right flow control constructs for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to use nested loops here.

```
item=
while read -r first second _; do
  if [[ $first = REQUIRES ]]; then
    printf '%s REQUIRES %s\n' "$item" "$second"
  else
    item=$first
  fi
done <inputfile
```

Invocation and output demonstrated at http://ideone.com/JejDyG

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ ^[A-Z]$ ]] && one="$line"
  [[ $line =~ ^REQUIRES(.*) ]] && echo "$one $line"
done < "file"
```

Example

```
> ./abovescript
Y REQUIRES Z
A REQUIRES B
C REQUIRES D
C REQUIRES E
C REQUIRES F
G REQUIRES H
I REQUIRES J
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `awk`

```
$  awk 'NF==1{a=$1};NF>1{print a,$0}' file
Y REQUIRES Z
A REQUIRES B
C REQUIRES D
C REQUIRES E
C REQUIRES F
G REQUIRES H
I REQUIRES J
```